# Jenkins Build Error in Angular Project After Changing a Hardcoded String

Tags: angular, jenkins, npm, build, node-modules

I recently modified a hardcoded string in my Angular project and made a push. Subsequently, Jenkins reported a build error. Here's the error message:

```scss
npm verb stack Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, open '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ui-package/node_modules/.staging/@types/sizzle-2fe905e6/package.json'
npm verb stack at Error (native)
npm verb cwd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ui-package
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/var/lib/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v6.14.4/bin/node" "/var/lib/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v6.14.4/bin/npm" "i" "--verbose"
npm ERR! node v6.14.4
npm ERR! npm v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ui-package/node_modules/.staging/@types/sizzle-2fe905e6/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! errno -20
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, open '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ui-package/node_modules/.staging/@types/sizzle-2fe905e6/package.json'
npm ERR!
```

Has anyone any solution for this please?

Comment: Have you tried trigger the pipeline without said change? 
If you really did only change a hardcoded string in a UI component then my guess would be that the issue is not related to that.
Try removing node_modules in the jenkins instance

Comment: Now, reverting back to previous versions are not building as well. So, not getting what has happened inside jenkins.

Comment: It’s more than likely a corrupt node_modules. Have you tried deleting node_modules and retriggered the build?